# Repeat iteration in enhanced-for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

### Regular for-loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // ...

    if (iWantToRepeat) {
        i--;
        continue;
    }

    // ...
}
```

### Enhanced for-loop

```
for (Foo f : Bar) {
    // ...

    if (iWantToRepeat) {
        // What can I put here?
    }

    // ...
}
```

Is there any way to repeat an iteration of an enhanced for-loop? I get the feeling there might be because it's based on iterators and if I had access to them I could do it I think.

Comment: Why would you want to repeat an iteration for one element?

Comment: You can't, basically. That's not a use case the enhanced-for-loop was designed for.

Comment: Short Answer: No. There is no guarantee that the underlying iterator even remembers the element it just served up.

Comment: Iterator in for-each loop is initiated without Your knowledge, and You do not have access to it.

Comment: FWIW, it's ugly to repeat by "undoing" the operation. Consider: `for (int i = 0; i < 10;) { .. if (!repeat) { i++; } }` as an alternative.

Comment: My first Jon Skeet reply *.*

Comment: @user2864740 I didn't know you could just leave out the third part of that for-loop.

Comment: @user2864740 There are some situations where I want to immediately stop executing the for-loop and repeat the iteration, I can't do that with your code though, I need to use `i--` and `continue`.

Comment: @ooxi This is a way to "simulate" a nested loop

Comment: @Ogen I've *never* run into one of those.

Comment: @Ogen you can even write `for(;;)` to create a infinite loop, it's equivalent to while(true)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot repeat an element going back in the loop. The only solution is adding a new loop inside the enhanced for. In my opinion this should be the way to do that even in a classic for, going forth and back is not very clean and can be harder to understand when reviewing the code.

```
for (Foo f: bar) {
   boolean notEnough=false;
   do {
      ... //this code will be always executed once, at least
     // change notEnough to true if you want to repeat
   } while (notEnough);
}
```

or

```
for (Foo f: bar) {
   boolean notEnough=chooseIfYouWantToRunIt();
   while(notEnough) {
      ... //this code can be not executed for a given element

   } 
}
```

Comment: The second approach is too complex, because is user doesn't want to continue looping one element, he should explicitly assign `false` to `notEnough`

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg Good, point! I agree, and the `do` loop ensures always at least one execution, but maybe there is a scenario where it suits better a while... maybe starting as false (no-op iteration). Edited

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't. In every iteration the [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) procedes by 1 step. However you can use a do-while loop to get the same effect:

```
for (Foo f : Bar) {
    boolean iWantToRepeat;
    do {
        // ...
        iWantToRepeat = //...;
        // ...
    } while(iWantToRepeat);
}
```

Comment: `iWantToRepeat = false;` should be in the first line of loop body

Answer (score 3):

You should view the enhanced for loop as purely a shortcut for the 95% of times you just need to iterate through something, without doing anything "unusual" that it doesn't support (modifying what you're iterating through, iterating through some elements more than once, etc.)

However, if your use case falls into one of the above categories, you'll just have to fall back to using the standard for loop (it's hardly that much more code to write, after all, and is certainly much better than hacking around a for each loop to get the same result.)